# How to check if the template parameter of the function has a certain type?

Tags: c++, templates, typechecking

Say I have a function with template type *T* and two other classes *A* and *B*.

```
template <typename T>
void func(const T & t)
{
    ...........
    //check if T == A do something
    ...........
    //check if T == B do some other thing
}
```

How can I do these two checks (without using Boost library)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you literally just want a boolean to test whether `T == A`, then you can use `is_same`, available in C++11 as `std::is_same`, or prior to that in TR1 as `std::tr1::is_same`:

```
const bool T_is_A = std::is_same<T, A>::value;
```

You can trivially write this little class yourself:

```
template <typename, typename> struct is_same { static const bool value = false;};
template <typename T> struct is_same<T,T> { static const bool value = true;};
```

Often though you may find it more convenient to pack your branching code into separate classes or functions which you specialize for `A` and `B`, as that will give you a *compile-time conditional*. By contrast, checking `if (T_is_A)` can only be done at runtime.

Comment: What do you mean, only done at runtime? `is_same<T,A>::value` is an integer constant expression. Code in `if(T_is_A)` is likely to be subject to dead code removal in a decent compiler, that happens before runtime. The problem is that the code in both branches still has to compile before it's eliminated.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Well, that optimization is a detail... the main point is as you say, though, that all the branch code has to be valid code, which is quite a restriction. By contrast, specialized templates aren't required to make sense unless they're actually instantiated.

Comment: This solution has an advantage against already proposed ones, cause if  "do something" and "do some other thing" were define a variable as a double and define a variable as int, the function specialization technic will not work as those variable would be local for those functions. Thanks for nice solution!

Answer (score 7):

Create function templates with specializations, that will do the thing you want.

```
template <class T>
void doSomething() {}

template <>
void doSomething<A>() { /* actual code */ }

template <class T>
void doSomeOtherThing() {}

template <>
void doSomeOtherThing<B>() { /* actual code */ }

template <typename T>
void func(const T & t)
{
    ...........
    //check if T == A do something
    doSomething<T>();
    ...........
    //check if T == B do some other thing
    doSomeOtherThing<T>();
}
```

Comment: If you omit the definition of the primary template altogether, `template <class> void doSomething();`, then you'll get a nice compile-time error if the type is neither `A` nor `B`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Actually, in this case, you'd get a compile time error regardless of `T`, because the specialization would fail to find its primary template. That's why both are included :)

Comment: Indeed, you'd have to omit the general definition and add a do-nothing definition for `doSomething<B>` and `doSomeOtherThing<A>`.

Comment: Yeah, I misread the OP's question as a "switch" on `T`, but that's not actually what was asked for. Never mind :-S

Comment: @SteveJessop: why? I don't understand.

Comment: @jpalacek: you'd have to do that in order to get the effect Kerrek described, I mean. Although come to think of it, it might then be pointless using a template at all, an overloaded function for `A` and `B` would do assuming that the code left out by the questioner actually uses `t`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, but the semantics would be slightly different. It would need an actual `T` as argument (not a problem, OP probably wants to use it anyway) and it would specialize on `T`s that are not `A`, but are convertible to `T` (or `T&`, depends on how you do it).

Comment: Good point about conversion. Even if I use non-const `T&` for my overload, a type derived from `A` would convert, and so it's a matter of whether the questioner actually wants an exact type check (i.e. expects violation of LSP), or is happy for derived classes of `A` to behave like `A`. Probably if we stepped back far enough to answer that question, we'd come up with even more possible mechanisms.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have a special implementation of `func` for some parameter type, simply create an overload specific for that type:

```
template <typename T>
void func(const T & t) {
   // generic code
}

void func(const A & t) {
   // code for A
}
```